# Assignment using call()

Tags: r

Suppose I want to manipulate function body like this:

```
> f1 = function(a, b, d) {
+   stop("This is a template!")
+   result
+ }
> body(f1)[[2]] = call("<-", as.name("result"), lapply(letters[1:2], as.name))
```

This *looks* good...

```
> f1
function (a, b, d) 
{
    result <- list(a, b)
    result
}
```

...but doesn't work:

```
> f1(a = 123, b = 456, d = 999)
[[1]]
a

[[2]]
b
```

On the other hand, when I do this:

```
> body(f1)[[2]] = call("<-", as.name("result"),
+                      as.call(c(as.name("list"), lapply(letters[1:2], as.name))))
```

It *looks* the same...

```
> f1
function (a, b, d) 
{
    result <- list(a, b)
    result
}
```

...but it works:

```
> f1(a = 123, b = 456, d = 999)
[[1]]
[1] 123

[[2]]
[1] 456
```

Can somebody please break this down for me into some really small pieces and explain what exactly is happening here?

Comment: You can check the `str` `as.call(c(as.name("list"), lapply(letters[1:2], as.name))) %>% as.list %>% str` and `lapply(letters[1:2], as.name) %>% str`

Comment: @akrun clearly, the two are different, the former having the call to list as its first element. Does this mean that in my first example, the "list" in the function body is a list of names that will not be evaluated, and in the second example, a call to list that will be evaluated? Is that what Konrad Rudolph means by `deparse` not being "perfect" (because they, confusingly, look the same even though they aren't)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `deparse` is not perfect. Incidentally this is unrelated to the assignment; the same problem exists when the expression is used in a different context, e.g.:

```
bquote(1 + .(lapply(letters[1:2], as.name)))
```

or

```
bquote(sum(.(lapply(letters[1:2], as.name))))
```

Either way, you’re constructing a list of names, but you are *not* constructing a call to `list` inside an unevaluated expression. But (I’m guessing that) the R deparser doesn’t know what to do with a list of names in an expression, since that situation can’t occur in real R code that isn’t constructed via unevalued expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can see now that the assignment part is incidental. I'm open to renaming the question to something more to the point. As for the examples: What do they show, besides the ability to create invalid expressions? Is the "imperfection" of the deparser that it doesn't know they're invalid? Thanks again!

Comment: @jakub Yeah, the examples were just to show that `deparse` fails to express the list literal properly when used as an operand in a compound expression. Ideally `deparse` would render these examples differently but I don’t really have a good idea how.